# How many client SDK or protocol that Apache IoTDB supports?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb

I'm trying to test IoTDB 0.11.4 on my local PC. Besides the java and python client, is there any other languages SDK supported? Like c#, erlang or golang...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome on StackOverflow.
Indeed, as the Communication between the Client and the IoTDB Server is based on Apache Thrift (https://thrift.apache.org/) it is *convenient* to develop other Clients.

Currently there exists:

- C++ (https://github.com/apache/iotdb/tree/master/client-cpp)
- Python (https://pypi.org/project/apache-iotdb/ / https://github.com/apache/iotdb/tree/master/client-py)
- Go (https://github.com/apache/iotdb-client-go)

If there is another language that you like to see supported you are very welcome to join the development team and start based on the Thrift definitions here: https://github.com/apache/iotdb/blob/master/thrift/src/main/thrift/rpc.thrift (that is the complete communication protocol between client and server). Some more information can also be found in the documentation here: http://iotdb.apache.org/UserGuide/Master/Communication-Service-Protocol/Programming-Thrift.html. The documentation itself states

> Thrift is a remote procedure call software framework for the
> development of extensible and cross-language services. It combines a
> powerful software stack and code generation engine, In order to build
> seamlessly integrated and efficient services among programming
> languages ​​such as C++, Java, Go, Python, PHP, Ruby, Erlang, Perl,
> Haskell, C#, Cocoa, JavaScript, Node.js, Smalltalk, and OCaml.
>
> IoTDB server and client use thrift for communication. In actual use,
> it is recommended to use the native client package provided by IoTDB:
> Session or Session Pool. If you have special needs, you can also
> program directly against the RPC interface

Comment: Support for C# was requested and closed by naming 2 projects (currently the second seems to be more active) https://github.com/apache/iotdb/issues/1742 - I'd prefer to see an official support for this and other clients.

Comment: @SimonSimCity i agree with you and we should reopen the issue!